# Kinect No Image received

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,i am using ubuntu12.04 and hydro in VMware.i installed openni-camera,openni-launch,and  SensorKinect,when I tried to view the data using openni_camera package,

```
yake@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch
```

It shows the following message:

```
[ INFO] [1425880374.263482333]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1425880374.264281088]: 1. device on bus 001:17 is a SensorKinect (2bf) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1425880374.266841490]: Searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1425880376.162143780]: Opened 'SensorKinect' on bus 1:17 with serial number '0000000000000000'
[ INFO] [1425880377.080038868]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1425880377.080617873]: depth_frame_id = '/camera_depth_optical_frame'
[ WARN] [1425880377.085363076]: Camera calibration file /home/yake/.ros/camera_info/rgb_0000000000000000.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1425880377.085733467]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
[ WARN] [1425880377.086030252]: Camera calibration file /home/yake/.ros/camera_info/depth_0000000000000000.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1425880377.086327993]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

Output of lsusb:

```
yake@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 045e:02be Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 045e:02bf Microsoft Corp.
```

To view the video, i therefore run:

```
$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

but it only have a  image windows,have not receive data from kinect.when i run:

```
$ rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity
```

it also have not image data,but we can see the depth camera  turn on.
Please help me!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204518/kinect--no-image-received/) by [Coco](https://answers.ros.org/users/21420/coco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-09**:
You might need to add some rules in :

```
etc/udev/rules.d
```

**Comment by [rdhn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20187/rdhn/) on 2015-03-10**:
Were you able to view the image in RVIZ? I am having similar issue. I am able to see the image from rosrun rviz rviz command but the rosrun image_view . . . . command is not giving any data, just a blank screen.

**Comment by [Coco](https://answers.ros.org/users/21420/coco/) on 2015-03-12**:
I can view the image not only in RVIZ but also in image_view.I can not give you specific reason why you only have  a blank screen.I guess your image path have some problem if RVIZ can get the image, I suggest that you can follow the book "example by ROS" step by step to execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had the same problem two years ago. I could never get the Kinect picture to show until I stopped using a virtual machine and set up a dual-boot of Ubuntu.

Here are my steps:
http://answers.ros.org/question/63428/turtlebot-2-on-virtual-machine-with-no-kinect-picture/

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [BlitherPants](https://answers.ros.org/users/4967/blitherpants/) with karma: 504 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) on 2015-03-11**:
worked for me, I bought a cheap laptop to run the ROS instead of using a vm on my good laptop.

**Comment by [Coco](https://answers.ros.org/users/21420/coco/) on 2015-03-12**:
Thanks,I got the picture when I stopped using Vmware and Wubi.I guess the reason is I can not get the correct  drivers when i use Vmware.I got 3 driver when i use a natural Ubuntu12.04.